# updating instance variable via appending in a function... not working?

Tags: python, class, variables, instance, instantiation

I am going to try and add all relevant code here first and then explain my issue. More of a newbie in python for sure, just wanted to do a project that I felt would be challenging to me so I am trying to do something that is a bit like 'And Then There Were None', Clue, and Among Us if that helps for context.

Function 1 - randomly determines what room a character will move to, updates all that players room info, and adds that character to the list of characters in the instance of the room. This seems to be where the issue is?

```
#room_options is list of rooms that depends on what room char is currently in. Passed in from instance object.

all_rooms = [hallway, kitchen, living_room]
def set_next_room(room_options):
    completed_chars = []
    for room in all_rooms:
        characters_in_room = room.get_occupants()
        characters_in_room = characters_in_room[:]
        #empties room so new characters can be assigned to room
        room.characters.clear()
        #if the person in characters in room is in completed characters, take them out of the characters in room list that will be run in next for loop
        for char in characters_in_room[:]:
            if char in completed_chars:
                characters_in_room.remove(char)
        #sets new rooms for each character in each room
        for char in characters_in_room:
            rand_int = randint(0, len(room_options)-1)
            rand_room = room_options[rand_int]
            #sets next room based on available choices
            char.set_next_room(rand_room)
            #adds character to the next room character list
            next_room = function_mapping_rooms(char.get_next_room())
            next_room.characters.append(char) #this line is not working??
            #changes rooms from current to previous, next to current, and next to None
            char.set_prev_room(char.get_current_room)
            char.set_current_room(next_room.name)
            char.set_next_room(None)

            #adds person to the completed list so room determination is not duplicated
            completed_chars.append(char)
```

Function 2 - not particularly important to the question, but included because this function is called above... more context

```
def function_mapping_rooms(room_name):
    characters = {
        'hallway': hallway,
        'kitchen': kitchen,
        'living room': living_room,
        'player death': player_death,
        'accusation': accusation
    }
    return characters.get(room_name)
```

basic example class of a room

```
class Kitchen:
    def __init__(self, name, weapon, characters):
        self.name = name
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.characters = characters
        self.room_options = ['hallway', 'living room']
    
   def enter(self):
        set_next_room(self.room_options)


kitchen = Kitchen('kitchen', 'kitchen knife', [])
```

So the issue is this. Based on my understanding of the code, the line `next_room.characters.append(char)` in the first block of code should be adding a character from `characters_in_room` to `self.characters` in the instance of the class "kitchen." When I run the code thru a debugger, the list of characters for the room does update. However, once the `set_next_room` function is done and I want to use the newly updated characters list, the list `self.characters` comes up as empty. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is? I am guessing it has something to do with memories and storage?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you're describing shouldn't happen.   `next_room` should be getting the global `kitchen` object, and `next_room.characters.append` should be modifying the list in place.  You might do `assert next_room is kitchen`, or something like that.  Note that you probably don't need different classes for each room.  The rooms are just different instances of a `Room` class, right?

Comment: When you say "However, once the set_next_room function is done and I want to use the newly updated characters list, the list `self.characters` comes up as empty" - you mean `self.characters` is empty within the same process right (as in the code has not "completed" yet and is still running)? You brought up potential issues with "memories and storage" so I just wanted to confirm that you are not trying to access `self.characters` after the process has ended because at that point it will no longer be accessible because it is no longer in RAM.

Comment: @TimRoberts just to build foundational knowledge I have been doing each room as a child class of a class called "Scene" but yes, I recognize each room class could just be an instance. When you mention global `kitchen`, are you saying the `kitchen` I am getting from the `function_mapping` function is not the same as the `kitchen` that is instantiated?

Comment: @Phoenix Good clarifying question. Yes, I know the script is still running. I meant once the `set_next_room` function is completed after it is called. In, regards to memory/storage: I guess I was thinking more along the lines of, is the `next_room.characters` list I am appending being stored in memory at a different location than `self.characters` for the `kitchen` object? And that is why I am getting an empty `self.characters` list in the object?

Comment: Given the tiny snippets of code you've shown us, the `kitchen` from `function_mapping` SHOULD be the same as the global object, but I'm suggesting you double-check that.

Comment: @TimRoberts Ok. Double checked and using the assertion didn't throw any errors. I tried hard coding it to append every character to `kitchen` instead of a random room, but `kitchen.characters` still showed up empty after running through `set_next_room`. Really quite bizarre.

Comment: How are you checking that `kitchen.characters` is still empty?

Comment: Using debugger and checking `self.characters` in side bar as debugger runs

Comment: @TimRoberts Ok so I was working more and I discovered that inside the loop `for room in all_rooms:` the list of characters for each room updates and contains names. But once I get outside of that loop, the character lists for each room are empty. Basically I added a print statement inside the loop and then a print statement outside of it and discovered the difference. Is that a scope issue? Need to somehow define `next_room` outside the loop?

Comment: OK, looking closer, I see that you are calling several methods on those `char` objects, like setting their rooms.  Is it possible those methods are "helpfiully" deleting themselves from their existing room?  You may have too many cooks making the soup.

Comment: @TimRoberts your question sent me down a new rabbit hole and I think I have found the answer. `set_next_room` is a bit of a mess logically, and I knew that, but I thought it would work just fine. Turns out, it doesn't. As you can see, I call `room.characters.clear()` in the outermost for loop. If I assign characters to that new room, but the room hasn't yet been called as `room` in that outermost loop, then when the loop finally iterates over the room, it clears all characters from it, even if I have already added characters to it as their new room. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was faulty logic. I made the function much more complicated than I needed to. See corrected code below.

```
def set_next_room(room_options):
    completed_chars = []
    for room in all_rooms:
        characters_in_room = room.get_occupants()
        for char in characters_in_room[:]:
            if char in completed_chars:
                continue
            #determines random room from available choices and sets equal to character's next room
            rand_int = randint(0, len(room_options)-1)
            rand_room = room_options[rand_int]
            char.set_next_room(rand_room)

            #gets the objects for current and next rooms to enable instance character list manipulation
            current_room = function_mapping_rooms(char.get_current_room())
            next_room = function_mapping_rooms(char.get_next_room())
            print(next_room.name)
            next_room.characters.append(char)
            current_room.characters.remove(char)

            #changes character rooms from current to previous, next to current, and next to None
            char.set_prev_room(char.get_current_room)
            char.set_current_room(next_room)
            char.set_next_room(None)

            #adds character to completed list so room determination is not duplicated
            completed_chars.append(char)
```